# Fatal Error wp-settings.php on line 119

Tags: php, errors

Receiving this error message after a post update:

> Warning: require(/home/thomwhite/wparch.com/wp-includes/post-template.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/thomwhite/wparch.com/wp-settings.php on line 119
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/thomwhite/wparch.com/wp-includes/post-template.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/thomwhite/wparch.com/wp-settings.php on line 119

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked the permission of the files?
It seems that /wp-includes/post-template.php is not readable.

You can change the permissions using your ftp client.

Comment: Will look into your recommendation